# How to get a Rician fading channel matrix from a Rayleigh fading channel matrix?

Tags: fading-channel

I have a Rayleigh fading channel matrix H. Let's say the dimension is 2000*128. Is there any way to convert this matrix into a Rician fading channel matrix for example κ = 5, 10, 15, etc.? Is there a formula for that?

Comment: I think Dilip really nailed this down, but it's absolutely true, you need to define what your "channel matrix" is. How exactly do you apply that matrix to what kind of transmit signal(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rician fading  channel is just a Rayleigh fading channel with a *specular* (that is, *unfaded*) signal component.  Depending on what exactly you mean by the  *Rayleigh fading channel matrix $H$*, the answer could be as simple as changing the *distribution* of each element of $H$ from a complex zero-mean proper Gaussian random variable to a complex Gaussian random variable with mean of the form $A_{m,n} \exp(j\theta_{m,n})$.

Comment: As far I know, 128 is the number of OFDM sub-carriers. And 2000 is the number of channel snapshots.